# find nth term of this sequence 3,18,41,72,111?

Tags: sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

find the $n$th term of this quadratic sequence: $$3,18,41,72,111,\dots$$
I did this an I kept getting the overall sequence wrong so please help.

Comment: If you [edit] the question to show us what you tried we may be able to help. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Since you already know it is a quadratic sequence, look at the first difference (step sizes), then the second difference (difference in consecutive step sizes). In each step you only lose an additive constant which you can determine from the values you have been given.

Comment: Alternatively, let the nth term $x_n$ be $an^2+bn+c$, substitute in the terms (3 of them will suffice to find the 3 unknowns), and solve for a, b, c.

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C18%2C41%2C72%2C111&language=english&go=Search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence is given by
$$
f(n)=4n^2+3n-4.
$$